# Are these 2 capabilities supported in Safari extension development?

Tags: safari-extension

I've written a Chrome/Opera extension and am **considering porting it to Safari**. It needs 2 specific capabilities and the absence of either would veto the whole plan.

1. **Ability to read HTTPS urls** - Chrome supports this as part of the "tabs" permission. Firefox (last I checked) does not.
2. **Ability to dynamically change the appearance of the activation button.** - In Chrome, this is achieved by having a single canvas on the background page (i.e. the button)...

   -body- -canvas id="button_canvas" width="19" height="19"- -/canvas- -/body-

... and then dynamically changing it whenever necessary ...

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("button_canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 19, 19);
// write stuff to the canvas
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 19, 19);
// key element below
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
   imageData: imageData
});
```

If anyone can answer these two questions definitively before I buy a used Mac on Craigslist, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

p.s. FWIW, my own Googling suggests that #2 is not possible in Safari. No idea about #1.

Answer (score 2):

I believe both are possible.

For HTTPS URLs: In the Safari extension builder, under **Extension Website Access**, set **Access Level** to **All** and tick the **Include Secure Pages** checkbox.

To dynamically change the icon displayed on a toolbar icon, first set any icon in the Safari extension builder. Then if you want to change in response to a toolbar button click:

```
safari.application.addEventListener('command', performCommand, false);

function performCommand(event) {
    if (event.command === 'changeIcon') {
        event.target.image = safari.extension.baseURI+'othericon.png';
    }
}
```

Under other circumstances, you can iterate your toolbar buttons to modify the one you want:

```
var toolbarButtons = safari.extension.toolbarItems;
for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; ++i) {
    var item = toolbarButtons[i];
    if (item.identifier === "mybutton") {
        item.image = safari.extension.baseURI+'othericon.png';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Secure pages, check. Buttons, sorta-check? Sounds like they're not truly dynamic... just replaceable. Which means I'd have to pre-package all the icons I need. Is that your understanding?

Comment: Yes, "replaceable" is probably a more accurate description. I'm not sure if the images must be pre-packaged - it may be possible to use images downloaded from the internet or specify them a data URL, I haven't tried.